# Google Closure Template Bitwise operator

Tags: javascript, google-closure-templates

I am using Google Closure template first time.
Can we use Bitwise operator in Google Closure Template.
I want to use some thing like this:

```
{if $saleStatus.errors & $constant.displayValue}
<div class="displaye">   
<msg desc="user is banned">   
User is Banned.
</msg>   
</div>    
{/if}
```

Here i want to use Bitwise operator but i throws error of Syntax Exception.
Or is there any way i should use. May be to include js and do something there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitwise AND is not a supported operator in Google Closure templates. You should evaluate this in JavaScript prior to calling the template, and pass it in as a parameter. [See the list of supported operators.](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/concepts#expressions)

For example, something like this...

in JavaScript:

```
var err = saleStatus.errors & constant.displayValue;
$(elem).html(namespace.myTemplate, { err: err });
```

in Soy/closure:

```
....

/**
 * Example ...
 * @param err The error
 */
{template .myTemplate}
    {if err}
        <div class="displaye">   
            <msg desc="user is banned">   
                User is Banned.
            </msg>   
        </div> 
    {/if}
{/template}
```

For more information about the concepts, please see [the documentation.](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/concepts#commandsyntax)

Comment: its fine when i have only once but what happens if i have this in for each loop. like    {foreach saleStatus in saleStatuses}. in this case i have {saleStatus.errors} may different value each time.

Comment: Consider calculating these values prior to rendering the template. You can do this by looping over saleStatuses and adding a new property containing saleStatus.errors & constant.displayValue